# Informal use of adjective as adverb

Tags: adjectives, terminology, adverbs

Is there a specific grammatical term for the substitution, in non-formal contexts, of an adjective where strictly speaking, an adverb is required?

For example:

- That would *sure* be a fun trip to go on!
- My week has been going *good*, thanks!
- He's been looking at me *funny*.

... instead of *surely*, *well*, and *funnily*, respectively.

My understanding, which could always be wrong, is that these are not *flat adverbs*, because a flat adverb is one in which the adverb form is invariably the same as the adjective form:

- She ran as *fast* as she could, hitting her stride *hard*.

... as opposed to **fastly* or **hardly*. Here, the choice of *fast* and *hard* isn't based on register; those forms do not ever vary from the adjective forms.

There are many questions on this site about adjectives being used in place of adverbs. [Here is an example](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/8328/37040). But as far as I can tell, that question and similar ones ask for usage guidance rather than for the actual name of the grammatical phenomenon itself.

By contrast, I am *not* asking about when or whether to use adjectives in place of adverbs. I am asking what this feature of the language, that enables adjectives to stand in for adverbs in non-formal contexts, is called. So I do not believe my question is a duplicate, though of course I may have missed something that's exactly on point.

Pointers to scholarly sources that analyze this phenomenon from a linguistic point of view would be gratefully received.

Comment: This paper just calls it "use of adjective as adverb", and lists it as a common feature of non-standard English. And a blog post identifies it by various phrases such as "adjective-as-adverb". I'm not sure if there's an alternative, more concise name. https://www.cambridgeassessment.org.uk/Images/aspects-of-writing-non-standard-english-sep-2008.pdf https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2007/01/could-not-care-less-adverbs.html

Comment: Basically, the distinction between adjective and adverb, which was never a strong point of the English lexicon, is going fast. The confusion of the adverb-forming suffix _-ly_ of _happily_ and _surely_ with the adjective-forming _-ly_ of _friendly_ and _surly_ certainly does not help, nor do the many idioms where the adjective is used as an adverb. This is all of a piece of the English lexicon losing its distinctive POS; just about any meaningful word can be used as a noun, a verb, an adjective, or an adverb -- even occasionally a preposition or conjunction -- without change, in context.

Comment: @JohnLawler Soonly pretty, all Yoda talking we.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/602308/2085).

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177043/american-use-of-personal-regular).