# "Don't take it personally" vs. "Don't take it personal"

Tags: grammar, adverbs, flat-adverbs

I believe usage trumps authority when it comes to the rules of English. However, I also believe that errors are just errors.

I keep hearing "ly" being left off of words even in common idioms. Enough so that I'm starting to wonder if adverbs are out of style in the 2020s and I'm just too old.

Is "Don't take it personal" still the flagrant grammatical error I remember it being?

Comment: Have you checked in any dictionaries to see if they mention a flat adverbial usage? There are other threads here looking at flat adverbs and resultative/depictive constructions that look similar (eg 'the water froze solid'). But I'd certainly avoid this one; it's possibly considered more acceptable in the States than in the UK.

Comment: From [Nobel Prize–winning litterateur Bob Dylan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHAVeUbLpwY) (starting at 0:10): "I didn't mean to treat you so bad. / You shouldn't take it so **personal**. / I didn't mean to make you so sad. / You just happened to be there, that's all."

Comment: The doublethink in your first paragraph is truly impressive :)

Comment: candied, slang is slang, informal is informal.  You, and everyone else, is completely aware that "... personal" is just an informal version of the correct "... personally". What is it you're asking?  I could immediately post 50, maybe 100 questions, or perhaps a better word is "thoughts", on here saying "I've noticed that A is now often casually spoken as B."  Like, yes, you'll find 100s of people on this list who agree with you that the English-speaking world is becoming stunningly illiterate - ok, yes, agreed!

Comment: '"How are you?" "I am good."' 'Am' is clearly a verb here, as is the possibly implicit 'doing' but it's weird to hear somebody say "I am [doing] well." I think people are just colloquially bad at grammar, personally.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "it's possibly considered more acceptable in the States than in the UK." I am **so sick** of this type of seemingly uninformed comment. For just about every single instance of BrE speakers claiming around here that some colloquial speech is AmE, British English has tons of similar examples.  The Brits and other English speakers of the world from Cape Town to Sydney and Auckland etc. all have colloquial speech forms. Acceptability is a term best suited to an Agatha Christie novel and English drawing rooms.

Comment: This hits my ears like the U.S. regional "I'm telling you true."

Comment: Sounds like someone needs to learn to think different.

Comment: @Lambie there's a reason why Bernard Shaw (or whoever the real author was) said that America and the UK are “two nations divided by a common language". There are of course *some* significant differences in speech, styles and idioms. For example your comment, mocking American regional speakers, under tinfoils answer: *Yep, varmints who ain't got no book larning* is pure Americanism. Doesn't mean it's inferior to British English or unacceptable English, it's just very informal and it would never be heard or uttered by a born and bred English person.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh, "Yep, varmints who ain't got no book larning" isn't British? You must be kidding if you think I don't know that. My point was very clear. I am probably one of the few AmE speakers who is very familiar with BrE...

Comment: @Lambie then I misunderstood your earlier comment directed at Edwin: ""*it's possibly considered more acceptable in the States than in the UK*." I am so sick of this type of seemingly uninformed comment."

Comment: Duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177043/american-use-of-personal-regular. I agree it's more common (in AmE, and particularly internet-influenced BrE speakers) now than it was in 2014, updated answers or those addressing that history should be welcome there, closing it as a duplicate of this one asked more than 9 years later is insane.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on whether your definition of a flagrant grammatical error includes colloquial usage (since 1829!) as documented by, say, *The Oxford English Dictionary*:

> **personal**
>  <sup>ADVERB</sup>
> *colloquial*. **to take** (something) **personal**: = *to take (a thing) personally* at **personally** *adv.* 3c.
>  <sub>Source:
> [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Here are a few *OED* attested usages, including the earliest offered:

> <sub>**1829**   Oh! if you'd call anybody a contemptible fool—I
> don't take it personal—I think I had better adjourn. —E. Fitzball,
> *Flying Dutchman* ii. iii. 31</sub>
>
> <sub>**1845**   If my gun did not snap, call me a coward, and I
> won't take it personal. —T. B. Thorpe, *Big Bear of Arkansas* 27</sub>
>
> <sub>**1938**   Lem's different. He takes things personal. —M. K.
> Rawlings, *Yearling* xvi. 186</sub>

You might be old, but probably not that old.

Comment: Yep, varmints who ain't got no book larning.

Comment: @Lambie — “Many people have the notion that colloquial language is by its very nature inferior or incorrect; that when a word or phrase is dubbed ‘colloquial’ it is outlawed from respectable speech.... As a matter of sober fact, colloquial language at its best should be regarded as the standard or norm for most kinds of speaking, as well as for much writing.” [—Walter Barnes, “Effective Colloquial Language,” *The Virginia Teacher*, 1932](https://commons.lib.jmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2731&context=va-teacher)

Comment: I don't know what respectable speech is. I was merely adding fuel to your fire, to use a metaphor inappropriately but that makes my point. I am not judging anyone's speech. The fact you think I am is what's so amusing...

Comment: @Lambie — Insinuating that the speakers of the dialog above are illiterate sure sounds like judgement to me.

Comment: @TinfoilHat That was [somebody else](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/614296/dont-take-it-personally-vs-dont-take-it-personal#comment1560559_614296).

Comment: No, I didn't say illiterate. I said uneducated or unschooled. Illiterate means unable to read or write your own language.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Thinking that characterizing someone as illiterate is judgmental sounds judgmental to me. What's wrong with being illiterate?

Answer (score 13):

As Huddleston & Pullum (2002) note, there are a number of adverbs that are "identical in form with adjectives" but are "restricted to informal style" or "clearly non-standard" (p. 567). One example they give is the use of *real* in "That's real nice of you"; in formal contexts, of course, *really* would be used instead, but *real* is quite common.

It seems reasonable to put the *personal* in "take it personal" in the same category, though it's more marginal and largely restricted to this specific idiom. Ngram suggests that, while still much less common than "take it personally," "take it personal" has [increased in popularity over the past few decades in American English,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+it+personal%2Ctake+it+personally&year_start=1990&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) though it remains [exceedingly rare in British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+it+personal%2Ctake+it+personally&year_start=1990&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3). I suspect that Ngram may be underestimating the frequency of "take it personal," since this construction presumably occurs more often in informal speech than in written works.

Comment: I believe the use of "real" instead of "really" as an adverb is still much more common in the US than in the UK.